# Airflow how to use input variable as default arg unless input variable not found

Tags: airflow

In Airflow, is it possible to use an input variable as a default_arg, but also have that arg safely resolve to an alternative if that input variable isn't given?

I'm trying for something like this:

```
default_args = {
        "example": "{{ params['example'] if 'example' in params else None }}"
}
```

but it's not resolving the following error I keep receiving when I trigger a DAG without 'example' as an input var:
**jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'example'** - this occurs upon execution of the first task instance that uses `@apply_defaults`

Comment: default_args should have key that exists in Operators. "example" is not on of those keys. do you want to define params default with "example" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define "example" in params. this way "example" will always be exist and will have the default value if not given.

```
from airflow.models import Param

default_args = {
    "params": {
        "example": Param(None, type=['null', 'string']),
    }
}
```